# Debugging postfix calculator

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack, postfix-notation

My task is to build a postfix calculator using a linked list to represent the stack. I have written the following code for the calculator, however I am receiving a compiler error that I do not understand. The error is coming from the postfixcalc.cpp file and is happening in the if-statement at operand2 = opers.getTop(op). The error reads, "value not ignored as it ought to be". I am using Dev-C++ and have never encountered this type of message. Any insight would be appreciated. Also, I can provide the StackP files if needed.

```
/** @file postfixcalc.h*/
#include "StackP.cpp"
#include <string>

using namespace std;
const int MAX_CHARS = 100;

class postfixcalc
{
public:
/** Default constructor. */
    postfixcalc();

// postfixcalc operations:
    void read();
    void show();
    int eval();

private:
    string e;
    Stack opers;
    char stringInput[MAX_CHARS];
    char *p;
};


/** @file postfixcalc.cpp*/

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "postfixcalc.h"

using namespace std;

postfixcalc::postfixcalc()
{}

void postfixcalc::read()
{
    cout << "Please enter a postfix expression: ";
    getline(cin, e);

}//end read

void postfixcalc::show()
{
    cout << e << endl;
}//end show

int postfixcalc::eval()
{
    int operand1, operand2, result;
    int op;

    p = strtok(stringInput, " ");
    while(p)
    {
    op = p[0];
    if( op == '+' || op == '-' || op == '*' || op == '/')
    {
        operand2 = opers.getTop(op);
        opers.pop();
        operand1 = opers.getTop(op);
        opers.pop();

        switch(op)
        {
            case '+':
                    result = operand1 + operand2;
                    break;
            case '-':
                    result = operand1 - operand2;
                    break;
            case '*':
                    result = operand1 * operand2;
                    break;
            case '/':
                    result = operand1 / operand2;
                    break;
        }//end switch
        opers.push(result);
    }
    else
    {
        opers.push(op);
    }
    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
}//end while
}//end eval
```

Here is the implementation of StackP

```
/** @file StackP.h */

#include "StackException.h"
typedef int StackItemType;

/** ADT stack - Pointer-based implementation. */
class Stack
{
public:
// Constructors and destructor:

   /** Default constructor. */
   Stack();

   /** Copy constructor.
    * @param aStack The stack to copy. */
   Stack(const Stack& aStack);

   /** Destructor. */
   ~Stack();

// Stack operations:
   bool isEmpty() const;
   void push(const StackItemType& newItem) throw(StackException);
   void pop() throw(StackException);
   void pop(StackItemType& stackTop) throw(StackException);
   void getTop(StackItemType& stackTop) const
      throw(StackException);

private:
   /** A node on the stack. */
   struct StackNode
   {
      /** A data item on the stack. */
      StackItemType item;
      /** Pointer to next node.     */
      StackNode    *next;
   }; // end StackNode

   /** Pointer to first node in the stack. */
   StackNode *topPtr;
}; // end Stack

/** @file StackP.cpp */

#include <cstddef>   // for NULL
#include <new>       // for bad_alloc
#include "StackP.h"  // header file

using namespace std;

Stack::Stack() : topPtr(NULL)
{
}  // end default constructor

Stack::Stack(const Stack& aStack)
{
   if (aStack.topPtr == NULL)
      topPtr = NULL;  // original list is empty

   else
   {  // copy first node
      topPtr = new StackNode;
      topPtr->item = aStack.topPtr->item;

      // copy rest of list
      StackNode *newPtr = topPtr;    // new list pointer
      for (StackNode *origPtr = aStack.topPtr->next;
       origPtr != NULL; origPtr = origPtr->next)
      {  newPtr->next = new StackNode;
         newPtr = newPtr->next;
     newPtr->item = origPtr->item;
      }  // end for

      newPtr->next = NULL;
   }  // end if
}  // end copy constructor

Stack::~Stack()
{
   // pop until stack is empty
   while (!isEmpty())
      pop();
   // Assertion: topPtr == NULL
}  // end destructor

bool Stack::isEmpty() const
{
   return topPtr == NULL;
}  // end isEmpty

void Stack::push(const StackItemType& newItem)
        throw(StackException)
{
   // create a new node
   try
   {
      StackNode *newPtr = new StackNode;

      // set data portion  of new node
      newPtr->item = newItem;

      // insert the new node
      newPtr->next = topPtr;
      topPtr = newPtr;
   }
   catch (bad_alloc e)
   {
      throw StackException(
     "StackException: push cannot allocate memory.");
   }  // try
}  // end push

void Stack::pop() throw(StackException)
{
   if (isEmpty())
      throw StackException("StackException: stack empty on pop");
   else
   {  // stack is not empty; delete top
      StackNode *temp = topPtr;
      topPtr = topPtr->next;
      // return deleted node to system
      temp->next = NULL;  // safeguard
      delete temp;
   }  // end if
}  // end pop

void Stack::pop(StackItemType& stackTop) throw(StackException)
{
   if (isEmpty())
     throw StackException("StackException: stack empty on pop");
   else
   {  // stack is not empty; retrieve and delete top
      stackTop = topPtr->item;
      StackNode *temp = topPtr;
      topPtr = topPtr->next;

      // return deleted node to system
      temp->next = NULL;  // safeguard
      delete temp;
   }  // end if
}  // end pop

void Stack::getTop(StackItemType& stackTop) const throw(StackException)
{
   if (isEmpty())
      throw StackException("StackException: stack empty on getTop");
   else
      // stack is not empty; retrieve top
      stackTop = topPtr->item;
}  // end getTop
```

This is the compiler error:

C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\My... In member function `int postfixcalc::eval()':

35 C:\Documents and Settings\Owner... void value not ignored as it ought to be

37 C:\Documents and Settings\Owner... void value not ignored as it ought to be

Comment: can you paste the complete error message from the compiler?

Comment: what is StackP.cpp ? why not use stl stack? please post the implementation of it.

Comment: As an aside, Dev-C++ is old, no longer maintained, and ships with an ancient compiler version (GCC 3.4.5, when the current is 4.7). You might try [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) instead for a similar environment with many improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Stack::getTop(StackItemType& stackTop) const throw(StackException)

int postfixcalc::eval()
{
int operand1, operand2, result;
    operand2 = opers.getTop(op);
```

The `getTop` function does not return anything, and then you take that nothing and store it in an `int`.  I think you wanted something more like this for that line:

```
   opers.getTop(operand2);
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I see the problem now and I think I have it figured out. You guys are life savers.

Comment: @user1277102: Be sure to upvote all answers that are helpful (on the left), and _eventually_ use the checkmark to mark one answer as the best (also on the left.  you might want to wait a day or so)

Answer (score 1):

`Stack::getTop()` is declared like so:

```
void getTop(StackItemType& stackTop);
```

`void` means that the function doesn’t return a value. Thus, attempting to assign the result of calling `opers.getTop()` to `operand2` is not possible, because `getTop()` doesn’t return anything! `getTop()` takes a *reference* parameter, so it can assign the top value directly to the variable you pass:

```
opers.getTop(operand2);
```

Instead of writing your own `Stack` class, you could just use `std::stack`:

```
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::stack<int> stack;
    stack.push(3);
    std::cout << stack.top() << '\n';
    stack.pop();
}
```

…Unless of course this is a learning exercise, in which case simply file away the tip for the future. Once you know how something is done, you should take advantage of the fact that other people have already done the work for you in a reusable way.

Comment: I have posted the implementation of StackP for you so you can see what it is. My instructor wants me to use this instead of the stl stack.

Comment: @user1277102: Thanks. I already saw your update and have edited my answer.